# Do we need the [brain] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag doesn't really seem to be much use. [brain](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain) would seem a more appropriate  tag for a site like biology.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be the difference between brain-simulation and neuromorphic-computing tags?

Comment: I have a word: synonym.

Comment: So let's stick with just neuromorphic-computing, right?

Comment: Yeah...........

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of topics about AI/ANN wants to achieve a brain simulation, so maybe we can rename it to: [brain-simulation](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brain-simulation).